# Cannot access network from non-root users in terminal (Permission denied)

Tags: networking, permissions, shell, termux

#### Preamble

My problem is, to run specific commands (i.e., start specific processes, possibly at background) on boot. I've installed [Termux](https://termux.com), so I want to start some of its commands at boot time, such as `sshd` and `crond`. For some reason, I don't want to use [Termux:Boot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux.boot) application (mainly because it do things late).

I used a script written some time ago, which ables me to call a Termux command, running as the user which Termux shell itself starts as (so not to have problems with processes being run as root, and be able to access Termux commands, at the same time). It worked, however, there is a problem: The network access is denied.

#### How I found it is a permission denied problem, not something else?

Initially, let's say how I logined as the non-root Termux user. `whoami` gave me the Termux user name, which was `u0_a73`. As my phone was (and is) rooted, I could use `su` binary. So, I ran this:

```
$ su - u0_a73
```

Now, I should be able to run `sshd` command. No, it failed:

```
$ sshd
bad addr or host: <NULL> (No address associated with hostname)
```

Why? Focusing on most important parts, I ran [`ltrace`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ltrace) and [`strace`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) commands. To find what was going wrong, this command helped me a lot:

```
# # Find most syscalls exited with errors
# strace sshd 2>&1 | grep "= -1"
```

And resulted in:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/libc.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/libnetd_client.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/libc++.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/libm.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
getrandom(..., ..., ...)            = -1 ENOSYS (Function not implemented)
socket(PF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC, IPPROTO_IP) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC, IPPROTO_IP) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Duh! Look at the two last lines: Permission denied.

#### The Problem

**Note:** It important to note that the same problem does not exist with Termux shell itself, even with the same environment variables on both shells.

The problem is, I cannot connect to network devices, such as `wlan0` (WiFi) and `rmnet0` (Data). All commands that requests these accesses fails, like `sshd`, `ifconfig`, `wget` and `ping`.

So, after a lot of researching:

- I've found [this thread](https://groups.google.com/g/sluggers/c/g0XY-Qk5C3w). It also provides an answer to the problem. However, there are no `groupadd` or `usermod` commands (or `addgroup` or `moduser` either) on my Android box, anywhere. See [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/64586/manually-add-uid-to-a-system-group). It seems these commands may exist or not from device to device.
- Due to the note at the beginning of the current section, after running `id` command on both shells, I realized that, Termux shell's user is added on extra groups than my custom `su`-initialized shell. The Termux shell `u0_a73` user is on extra groups, including `inet`, `everybody` and `all_a73`.

  **Note:** Thanks for the helps, but please avoid saying "So you should add `u0_a73` in your custom shell in these groups, particularly the `inet` one!". Seems impossible in my environment. Read the previous item; I have no command to do this (Why? IDK).
- There's another room: Changing permissions (or possibly owners) of device files (or something else). While it should be considered as a temporary fix, as it might have security flaws, but, if you know how, then I'll appreciate you by an upvote (perhaps will not be my own answer).

I don't know if it helps or not, but when I use `su` provided by Termux and I run `ifconfig` inside, a bunch of these audit messages will be produced:

```
09-04 20:08:04.647 24951 24951 I ifconfig: type=1400 audit(0.0:2567): avc: denied { ioctl } for path="socket:[221195]" dev="sockfs" ino=221195 ioctlcmd=8912 scontext=u:r:magisk:s0 tcontext=u:r:magisk:s0 tclass=unix_dgram_socket permissive=1
09-04 20:08:04.647 24951 24951 W ifconfig: type=1300 audit(0.0:2567): arch=40000028 syscall=54 per=800008 success=yes exit=0 a0=3 a1=8912 a2=be83a738 a3=3 items=0 ppid=24888 auid=4294967295 uid=10073 gid=10073 euid=10073 suid=10073 fsuid=10073 egid=10073 sgid=10073 fsgid=10073 ses=4294967295 tty=pts19 exe="/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/ifconfig" subj=u:r:magisk:s0 key=(null)
```

So, how to fix this permissions problem, that is, the system blocks a non-root user from accessing network devices?

I'm using Android (custom ROM, ViperOS) 7.1.2 (rooted), with Magisk installed, kernel 3.10.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your process must be in group AID_INET (GID: 3003) (or have the capability NET_RAW) to create network sockets.

Comment: @IrfanLatif Please read first two items in "The Problem" section, again. There is a group named `inet` (3003), and I know if I'm in that group, the problem should be fixed. However, consider I have no way to do that; there's no `addgroup` or the like in my environment.

Comment: Read the linked answer. You don't need `addgroup` to add your process to a group. You can use e.g. `setpriv`. If you want to stick with `addgroup` approach, see my answers to [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/201285/218526) and [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209919/218526). However it won't work the way you are trying to make it work. To know why, again, read the answer I linked first.

Comment: @IrfanLatif OK, thanks for the links, really. As I have not enough time now, I'll check those tomorrow, and report it back.

Comment: @IrfanLatif Again, thanks for the links. Great resources. However, I cannot find a solution for my problem there. Maybe that's how complicated Android is implemented, maybe I don't understand things correctly. The only thing I know is that, doing these kind of stuff on Linux distros are much easier than on Android. This is the reason why I personally think Android have a long way to reach the point we could call it a good platform.

Comment: Well, Android disappoints those who expect it to be a usual Linux distro. It's not, and most probably never going to be. It uses the powers of Linux kernel, but userspace is entirely a different world. Androids provides no official tools, documentation, APIs or support to achieve what you want to do. We need to figure out some out-of -the-way solution. You can use this command to add `sshd` process to `3003` group: `setpriv --reuid 10173 --regid 10173 --groups 3003 -- sshd`. However if you run it from an app which holds INTERNET permission, all forked process are already in the said group.